# Delphi Web service TMemoryStream as a parameter

Tags: web-services, delphi

I try to build delphi webservice that copies files from client to server using TMemoryStream Object.

but when I declare a function like this:-

```
    function TCopyFiles.writeFile(KeyString: string; FileStream: TMemoryStream; 
ServerPath: string): String; stdcall;
```

And I get the following Error: Access violation at address 01F1AD82 in module 'CopyFiles.dll'. Read of address 00000001/EAccessViolation

I think that the solution is to register TMemoryStream Type but I don't know how to register these type.

Comment: Usually a DLL function should not be a member of class (and I suppose `stdcall` means that it is called from a DLL). How exactly is the function called?

Comment: Methods have implicit first parameter - a pointer to the object instance, so you will get a data type mess